# Are all derivatives of sinc function bounded on real axis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

It seems that all derivatives of $sinc$ function ($sinc(x)=sin(x)/x$) are bounded on real axis. Is it true or no?

Comment: [This was also posted to MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/215761/1916). Please note that [crossposting between SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/64068) - try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site. If you insist on posting in many sites, at least provide links to the other posts - as you can imagine, it would be frustrating for someone to put time into answering your question here, only to find out that you'd already gotten an answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The Fourier transform of $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$ is a step with support on $[-1,1]$, so it (and also all its derivatives) is an entire function of exponential type 1. From  the Berstein inequality $$\sup_{\mathbb R}|f'(x)|\le \sup_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|$$ for such functions and the fact that $\sup_{\mathbb R}|\mathrm{sinc}(x)|\le1$ it follows that $$\sup_{\mathbb R}|\mathrm{sinc}^{(n)}(x)|\le1,\quad n\ge1.$$

Comment: Thanks! I also used the fact that sinc is an entire function (therefore it's bounded on any bounded interval). As for the behavior as $x \to \infty$, it can be shown by induction on $n$ that $sinc^{(n)}(x)$ is a fraction such that the "degree" of its numerator (w.r. to x) is smaller than the "degree" of denominator, and therefore $\lim_{x \to \infty} sinc^{(n)}(x)=0$  => this function is bounded on the real axis.